# Unable to fetch the Fuel type, AJAX works for the dependent dropdowns unable to fetch the FuelType in dropdown, instead None is returned

Tags: django, django-models

## models.py

```
class Car(models.Model):
Car_Name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
Car_Details = models.TextField()
Car_Price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
Car_Brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Fuel_type = models.ManyToManyField('FuelType')

def __str__(self):
    return self.Car_Name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('car_detail', args=[str(self.pk)])

class FuelType(models.Model):
    Fuel_Choices = (
        ('Petrol','petrol'),
        ('Diesel','diesel'),
        ('CNG','cng')
    )
    Fuel_Variant = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Fuel_Choices, default='1')

def __str__(self):
    return self.Fuel_Variant
```

## forms.py

```
class AjaxModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = model_class.objects.none()
        super(AjaxModelChoiceField, self).__init__(queryset, *args, **kwargs)
        self.model_class = model_class


def to_python(self, value):
    if value in self.empty_values:
        return None
    try:
        key = self.to_field_name or 'pk'
        value = self.model_class.objects.get(**{key: value})
    except (ValueError, self.queryset.model.DoesNotExist):
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'], code='invalid_choice')
    return value
    # a Custom Choicefield to populate Dropdown on Selection (let's ajax works)


class SearchCarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Car_Brand = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Brand.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), empty_label="Select Brand")
    Car_Name = AjaxModelChoiceField(model_class=Car, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), empty_label="Car Models", required=False)
    Fuel_type = AjaxModelChoiceField(model_class=FuelType, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), empty_label="Fuel Options", required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Car
    fields = ('Car_Brand', 'Car_Name', 'Fuel_type')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Car_Name'].queryset = Car.objects.all()
        if 'Brand' in self.data:
            try:
                brand_id = int(self.data.get('Car_Brand'))
                self.fields['Car_Name'].queryset = Car.objects.filter(Car_Brand_id=brand_id).order_by('Car_Name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty Car queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['Car_Name'].queryset = self.instance.Brand.Car_set.order_by('Car_Name')

        self.fields['Fuel_type'].queryset = FuelType.objects.all()
        if 'Car' in self.data:
            try:
                Car_id = int(self.data.get('Car_Name'))
                self.fields['Fuel_type'].queryset = FuelType.objects.filter(id=car_id).order_by('Fuel_type')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty Car queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['Fuel_type'].queryset = self.instance.Car.FuelType_set.order_by('Fuel_type')


def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SearchCarForm, self).clean()
        return cleaned_data
```

## views.py

function devised to fetch choices for fuel populated with Ajaxchoicefield from forms, similar function is used to dynamically fetch cars from thier brand name and works fine

```
def load_fuel(request):
    car_id = request.GET.get('Car_Name')
    fuel = Car.objects.filter(id=car_id)
    print(fuel)
    context = {
        'fuel': fuel,
    }
    return render(request, 'fuel_dropdown_list_options.html', context=context)
```

## fuel_dropdown_list_options.html

```
<option value="">Fuel options</option>
{% for fuels in fuel %} 
<option value="{{ fuels.id }}">{{ fuels.Fuel_type }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

## template view

[image: products.FuelType.none returned instead of fuel choices]

PS: I'm new to stackoverflow if something's missing/incomplete or i have posted something wrong, i apologise in advance

Comment: I don't see any actual question in your question.

Comment: actually I have saved a Fuel type And used manytomanyfield for saving more than one fuel option, and the issue is i'm unable to fetch the Fuel type when fetching it on the template end, AJAX works Fine so Far but i'm unable to fetch the Fuel Type in Select option as shown in the attachment in template view in the post

Comment: Edit that into your question, using the edit button on the bottom left of your post. Perhaps add a clear heading above it with "Question", whilst you're at it, could you also remove the django word from your title, that is what tags are for.

Comment: ohh ! ok Thanks, will update the post title.